# return a auto value in if block?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int test(int val)
{
    int *ptr;

    if(val == 0)
    {
        int val = 4;
        ptr = &val;
    }

    return (*ptr + 1);
}

int main(void)
{
    int i = test(0);
    printf("%d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

In the above code, the variable `val` in if block is destroyed, so in `return (*ptr + 1)` , the value `*ptr` should be undefined, but result of this program is `5`.

I know this is a undefined program, but it seems that it produces a expected value, why?

Comment: The value of `*ptr` is indeterminate, not undefined. It's your program that's undefined :)

Comment: I know this program is a undefined program, but it seems that it produces the expected ouput, why?

Comment: Then you don't understand the meaning/gravity of `undefined`. It really means anything can happen and whatever you see is happening is just an illusion. Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984/183120).

Comment: @Charles0429 By luck. The stack isn't used in-between, so the old value is kept. If you are on an embedded system or on DOS with interrupts or have a signal handler installed and you get a signal, things might look different.

Comment: @Charles0429 "it seems that it produces the expected output". So if it seems to be correct, then it can't possibly be incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already stated in the comments, it is undefined behaviour - so anything can happen.

However, *technically*, the reason is that the stack frame is not changed after leaving the `if` block, and that the compiler allocates all required local variables for the whole function at the beginning of the function, instead of creating a new stack frame for each scope. You can see this in the assembly code which is produced by your function:

```
ZL4testi:
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        pushq   %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        .cfi_offset 6, -16
        movq    %rsp, %rbp          ; set up base pointer for stack frame
                                    ; NOTE: The stack pointer is not modified here
                                    ; since you are not calling any other function
                                    ; from within `test`
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
        movl    %edi, -20(%rbp)     ; parameter was passed in %edi, store it in the frame

; if (parameter val == 0)
        cmpl    $0, -20(%rbp)       
        jne     .L2

; Here the scope of the `if` block starts - no changes to the stack frame setup!
; {
;    int val = 4
        movl    $4, -4(%rbp)        ; val is at -4(%rbp)

;    ptr = &val;
        leaq    -4(%rbp), %rax      ; get address of val into %eax
        movq    %rax, -16(%rbp)     ; store address of val into ptr
; }
.L2:
        movq    -16(%rbp), %rax     ; Here, ptr is still containing the address 
                                    ; of val within the stack frame
        movl    (%rax), %eax        ; load `val` from the stack even though it is out of scope
        addl    $1, %eax

        popq    %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
        ret
```

Throughout the whole function, the stack frame layout is

```
-20(%rbp)  => parameter val
-16(%rbp)  => ptr
 -4(%rbp)  => variable val inside the `if` block
```

Note that nothing prevents the compiler from **reusing** `-4(%rbp)` if you declare a new variable inside another scope at a later point inside your function:

```
static int test(int val) {
    int *ptr;

    if(val == 0) {
        int val = 4;
        ptr = &val;
    }
    if(val == 0) {
        int otherval = 6;
        ptr = &otherval;
    }
    return (*ptr + 1);
}
```

If you compare the previous assembly output with the one which is generated with the additional block in place, the only difference are these **additional** lines:

```
    cmpl    $0, -20(%rbp)
    jne .L3

    movl    $6, -4(%rbp)      ; here, -4(%rbp) is reused for otherval
    leaq    -4(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, -16(%rbp)
.L3:
```

Comment: Excellent answer. May I ask how you got the assembly code? Is that done within your IDE?

Comment: With `gcc`, you simply pass the `-S` flag to the compiler: `gcc -S -o test.s test.c` produces the assembly output in `test.s` (for some reason, I was using `g++` for my answer, but that does not change much besides the function name mangling)

Comment: @Andreas I declare a new variable after the if block, but the `-4(%rbp)` is not reused, how could I make the program reuse the `-4(%rbp)`?

Comment: @Andreas I also tried to declare a new variable in a new if block after the first one, but the `-4(%rbp)` is still not reused.

Comment: Well, since it is still `undefined behaviour` , it depends on your compiler and on your environment whether it is reused - when compiling with gcc 4.6.3 on x86_64, it is reused

Answer (score 0):

I don't see val being destroyed, simply changed to 4.

ptr is then given the value of 4

So 4+1 = 5

Maybe I'm missing something completely.

Comment: You are missing the fact that val is declared twice, once as parameter and once as local variable within the `if` block.

Comment: ptr is assigned and returned within that scope. I could see your point if you were trying to print out val itself outside of the scope.

Comment: But that is what he actually does - `ptr` points to the `int val = 4` variable which is out of scope after leaving the `if` block, hence it is pointing to undefined memory after leaving the `if` block. Whether this works is undefined, and technically depends on the compiler, the CPU type, the optimization level and probably more

Comment: Isn't he returning by value and not by reference?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the return value of the function - that is fine. The problematic part is where `ptr` is dereferenced (in `(*ptr + 1);`) - here, `*ptr` is returning an undefined value

Answer (score -1):

The function evaluates (*ptr + 1) to 5, and returns the 5. Nothing undefined here. If you want undefined behaviour, return the pointer, and access the memory through the pointer in `main`.

Comment: After the disappearance of `val`? I don't think so.

Comment: oops - did't notice he redefined val within the block.

Answer (score -1):

if you check the address of each pointer you can remark that is not the same address pointer:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    static int test(int val)
    {
        int *ptr;

        if(val == 0)
        {
            int val = 4;
            ptr = &val;
        }
        printf("ptr @ = %p \n",ptr);
        printf("val @ = %p \n",&val);
        return (*ptr + 1);
    }

int main(void)
{
    int i = test(0);
    printf("%d \n", i);
    return 0;
}  

==> 
    result :
    ptr @ = 0x7fff8b480874 
    val @ = 0x7fff8b48086c 
    5
```

==> is undefined behaviour but the difference between address of pointer can explain why the variable "i" have the good value

Comment: **Please** consider that **val is defined twice**!!!! The val address you are printing is the one from the parameter, not from the one where `ptr` is pointing to.

Comment: why consider that ? when the @ of ptr and val are not the same

Comment: Yes, they are not the same, but that does not answer the question. The `val` **parameter** has nothing to do with the scope issue - it could equally well be named `xyz` or whatever with the same result. See http://ideone.com/kiU628 and note that in that case, it does **NOT** print `5` but (for my run) `-1217749003` since they seem to use a different compiler.

Comment: I said maybe answer the question. because is undefined behaviour

Comment: I saw your answer , in the stack frame layout you display the address of pointer and are not the same (offsets are different )